# How do I get rhe right syntax for searching a string in a database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

List the state descriptions that start with “NEW” and the count of the employers located in that state. Be sure to list all of those states that start with “NEW” even if the count is zero. Make sure your column headings match what is shown below.

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| Description   | Number of Companies |
+---------------+---------------------+
| NEW HAMPSHIRE |                   0 |
| NEW JERSEY    |                   1 |
| NEW MEXICO    |                   0 |
| NEW YORK      |                  13 |
+---------------+---------------------+ 
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For this question I used:

```
SELECT state.description, COUNT(*) "Number of Commpanies"
FROM employer
WHERE SUBSTR(state.description, 1, INSTR(state.description, 'NEW')-1) AS "Number of Companies";
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS "N
umber of Companies"' at line 3
```

Why am I getting this and what is the right syntax. First of all, I'm not sure if I'm following the question correctly. The table as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE state;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| statecode   | char(2)     |      | PRI |         |       |
| description | varchar(30) |      |     |         |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec) mysql>
```

mysql>SELECT * FROM employer

```
| companyname                    | division         | address                   | city             | statecode | zipcode |
| Acme Information Source        | Customer Support | 132 Commerical Way        | Cleveland        | OH        |   44234 |
| Ajax Software, Inc.            | RandD            | 2421 West Industrial Way  | Berkeley         | CA        |   94710 |
| Ajax Software, Inc.            | Production       | 2421 West Industrial Way  | Berkeley         | CA        |   94710 |
```

Comment: you don't alias in where clause... alias can only be done through column display and tables.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a column alias is:

```
SELECT state.description, COUNT(*) AS "Number of Companies"
FROM employer
WHERE .. -- your logic here
```

You can't add a column alias after the WHERE, that doesn't make sense.

However, you have a way to go to actually answering the question. You refer to the `state` table, but you're not joining to it yet, for example.

Comment: Hmm, ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'state.description' in 'field list'

Comment: Yes, see my edit. You need to research how to `join` tables together.

Comment: @DanBracuk edited to make more clear that I am not fixing everything wrong with OP's code (since it's not even half implemented yet)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight Dan was talking to me, don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

A where clause has to resemble

```
where something = something
```

Yours resembles

```
where something as alias name
```

However, the simple answer is:

```
where state.description like 'NEW%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN, and you were missing a GROUP BY

```
SELECT
   s.description,
   COUNT(*) AS "Number of Companies"
FROM state a
JOIN employer e ON s.statecode = e.statecode
WHERE s.description LIKE 'NEW%'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT s.description, count(e.*) as "Number of Companies"
  FROM employer e left join state s on e.statecode = s.statecode 
 WHERE s.description like 'NEW%'
 GROUP by 1
```